# Using $expand on file properties of a lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a custom list and in that custom list I have a lookup referencing a document library. Is there a way for me to perform a rest operation such that I can also use $expand=File when querying the custom list.

Example

I can use the following:

> https://site/_api/lists/getbytitle('Navigation')/items?$select=Icon/Title,Image/Title,*&$expand=Icon/Title,Image/Title

I want to be able to expand the file properties as well similar to below:

> https://site/_api/lists/getbytitle('Navigation')/items?$select=Icon/Title,Image/Title,*&$expand=Icon/Title,Image/Title,Image/File

But I'm not getting any details of the file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.